# How to detect BB10 app already installed using a ported android app

Tags: android, blackberry-10

I have an Android Application which will detect whether an application is installed or not, after that it launches that application.
So the Android Code is

```
PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
boolean app_installed = false;
try {
    pm.getPackageInfo("com.mypackage.myactivity", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    app_installed = true;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    app_installed = false;
}
if(app_installed) {
    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mypackage.myactivity");
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
}
```

This works fine for Android. But when I convert my apk to bar file and then install it on a BB10 device then it doesn't recognises whether the application is installed or not.

Do i need to change the package name?

Please advice on this.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this. Only one version of a particular application can be installed on a BB10 device at a time. Sububsequent installs upgrade the application.

Comment: @Richard I am trying to determine whether some other application is installed or not."com.mypackage.myactivity" is some other application